# What is Marisa doing underground with a device on her back?

Tags: touhou-project

[image]

There is an unusual scene in the [opening of "The Memories of Phantasm"](https://youtu.be/Ap5910bTGLA?t=2m20s), in which we see Kirisame Marisa with some kind of measurement or detection device on her back. Does it have a reference in any Touhou anime, manga or novel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably referencing to a Touhou game which will be later adapted into an anime in the series.

A lot of the openings for "Memories of Phantasm" incorporate scenes from later episodes. For example, the opening of the first episode has scenes which later appeared in the next 3 episodes.

This scene:

[image]

Was in episode 2.

In the 5 openings so far there's lots of sneak previews of what appears to be references to other Touhou games: for example, [Subterranean Animism](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Subterranean_Animism) and  [Imperishable Night](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Imperishable_Night).

[image]

The scene with Marisa with a measurement devise on her back is almost certainly another reference Subterranean Animism to as the three characters shown - Nitori, Patchouli and Alice - are [Marisa's partner's in the game](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Subterranean_Animism/Gameplay#Character_Statistics). It is also underground which is where Subterranean Animism is set.

Furthermore in the game, the protagonists are given a device that [Yukari](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Yukari_Yakumo) made:

> But others got worried, and wanted them to go down into the Underworld, with a device Yukari Yakumo made so they could talk even underground.

Comment: Additional note: [Those 3 characters are Marisa partners in the game as well](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Subterranean_Animism/Gameplay#Character_Statistics), so it's certainly referring to Subterranean Animism, though they should not be on underground actually.

Comment: I edited it. is it alright?

Comment: Yep, no problem :)